# How demonstrate the Craig representation for the Gaussian probability function?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

The [Q-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-function) is defined by : 
$$Q(x) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{x}^{\infty}\exp(-\frac{u^2}{2}) \ \mathrm{d}u \ \ (1).$$

According to the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-function) page there is an alternative form of the [Q-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-function) based on [John W. Craig](http://wsl.stanford.edu/~ee359/craig.pdf)'s work  that is more useful is expressed as:
$$Q(x) =\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sin^2(\theta)}\right) \ \mathrm{d}\theta  \ \ (2).$$

Craig's proove is based on probabilistic  approach, there for I look for an analytic one.
any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @DavideGiraudo for fixing it.

Comment: here a way to solve this http://kaust.academia.edu/AhmadMawla/Papers/513176/Q-Function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since both expressions coincide at $x=0$, it suffices to show that their derivatives coincide on $x\geqslant0$. Since the derivative of the first expression of $Q(x)$ is proportional to $\mathrm e^{-x^2/2}$, this happens if $R(x)$ is constant on $x\geqslant0$, where
$$
R(x)=\mathrm e^{x^2/2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x}{\sin^2\theta}\mathrm e^{-x^2/(2\sin^2\theta)}\mathrm d\theta=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x}{\sin^2\theta}\mathrm e^{-x^2\cot^2\theta/2}\mathrm d\theta.
$$
The change of variables $v=x\cot\theta$ yields the range $v\gt0$ and the Jacobian $\mathrm dv=x\mathrm d\theta/\sin^2\theta$, hence
$$
R(x)=\int_0^{+\infty}\mathrm e^{-v^2/2}\mathrm dv,
$$
which does not depend on $x$. QED.

Comment: I am not sure that Craig's proof is based on a probabilistic approach.

Comment: Well Done @Didier, About the Craig's proof I refered to this [pdf document][1]. 
When I searching I found a book called  : "Probability Distributions Involving Gaussian Random Variables" state that :
<<The form in (l) is not readily obtainable by a change of variables directly in (2). However, by first extending (1) to two dimensions (x and y) where one of the dimensions (y) is integrated over the half plane, a change of variables from rectangular to polar coordinates readily produces (2).>> pg.123.  
If this is clear for you, how can be done? 
[1]:http://wsl.stanford.edu/~ee359/craig.pdf

Comment: Reference [1] is already in your post. As regards the other citation, its meaning is not clear to me at the moment.

Comment: Alright then, thanks anyway  :)